# Boolean is not a function in react native fetch function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

**Boolean is not a function react-native**
*When ever fetching API in react native  from device its giving Boolean is not a Function*

```
//Fetching a get api 
fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees', {
   method: 'GET'
})
.then((response) => response.json()) 
.then((responseJson) => {
   console.log(responseJson);
})
.catch((error) => {
   console.error(error);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, you've got extra ` sign:

fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees', {
      method: 'GET'
      })
      .then((response) => response.json()) 
      .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      });

Comment: Somewhere in the code you are doing a call like this (someVariable:Boolean).call/...

In short you may be trying to call a function on a boolean variable.

Answer (score -1):

variable declaration  was wrong ,

```
this.state ={
     isLoading:Boolean = true 
}
////instead of that we should be 
this.state ={
     isLoading: true 
}
```